# What is the practical rate limit for using Google+ API?

Tags: rest, oauth, google-plus, rate-limiting

We are planning to develop an application that may need to create a large number of (https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=xxx) calls to do token validations beyond the usage. And I am looking for the number about the rate limit...

I've found something related https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/#api but want to know the accurate number, can anyone provide the inforamtion (limit per token(user)/ limit per app)? ﻿